# Clickhouse : Inserting data with missing columns from parquet file

Tags: parquet, clickhouse

I have hundreds of different parquet files that I want to add to a single table on a Clickhouse database. They all contain the same type of data, but some of them have a few missing columns.

Is there still a way to add the data directly from those parquet files using a query such as

`cat {file_path} | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO table FORMAT Parquet"`?

If I try doing this, I get an error like this one :

```
Code: 8. DB::Exception: Column "column_name" is not presented in input data: data for INSERT was parsed from stdin
```

I tried adding to the missing column a NULL or DEFAULT value when creating the table, but I still get the same result, and the exception results in not adding any data from the concerned parquet file.

Is there an easy way to do this with Clickhouse, or do I just have either to fix my parquet files, or preprocessing my data and inserting it with another type of query format that doesn't use parquet?

Comment: You only can specify columns in the insert `INSERT INTO table(a,b,c,d) FORMAT Parquet`

Comment: Tried it, it does work and prevents the exception from happening.
I might go for the preprocessing my parquet files first option, since I would have to generate a different insert query for each parquet file. I would have to find the set of columns from the file and generate an insert query from this.

At this point, I might as well just fix my files first.

Thanks for the help, it does clear up the syntax for me!

Comment: You can use clickhouse-local to pipe into clickhouse-client as a preprocessing step. Refer: https://altinity.com/blog/2019/6/11/clickhouse-local-the-power-of-clickhouse-sql-in-a-single-command. It would avoid regenerating parquet.

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported in ClickHouse by providing the following setting:

```bash
input_format_parquet_allow_missing_columns = 1
```

The syntax in 23.xx versions is:

```bash
cat myfile.parquet  | clickhouse-client --query='INSERT INTO mytable SETTINGS input_format_parquet_allow_missing_columns = 1 FORMAT Parquet'
```

For versions older than 23.xx you provide the syntax after the FORMAT:

```bash
cat myfile.parquet | clickhouse-client --query='INSERT INTO mytable FORMAT Parquet SETTINGS input_format_parquet_allow_missing_columns = 1
```

Similar settings exists for `orc` files as well.